# Remove Elastic Beansalk URL Zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've previously setup applications with elastic beanstalk where the url was {environment-name}.elasticbeanstalk.com. Now however I'm seeing that there's a zone appended to my environment name, creating: {environment-name}.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. Is there a way to force the former format?

Comment: As far as I know you have no control over that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Mark B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13070/mark-b) has mentioned, it is not possible to change the main domains of the elastic beanstalk url. However you can configure a `CNAME` to point to your elastic beanstalk environment, thereby hiding the AWS domain completely.

Full instructions in the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) but you basically want to add a `CNAME` to your DNS so that you get the following

```
$ dig app.example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> app.example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 40373
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 9, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;app.example.com.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
app.example.com. 299 IN  CNAME example.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com.
```

Comment: Additionally if you are using Route53 you can create Aliases in place of CNAMES to your regional beanstalk environment URLs. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/01/aws-elastic-beanstalk-adds-support-for-amazon-route-53-aliasing/